# Read, encrypting and writing a block of bytes

Tags: c, fwrite, eof, fread

- read 16 bytes from a file;
- encrypt this 16 bytes;
- write encrypted bytes to another file;
- do the above things again until end of file;

If the last call is < 16 bytes i fill the buffer with 0.
Is this a correct way to do it?

```
FILE *fp = fopen("name", "r+");
FILE *fpout = fopen("name", "w+");
char plain_text[16];
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

while(!feof(fp)){
  memset(plain_text, 0, sizeof(plain_text);
  read_bytes = fread(plain_text, 1, 16, fp);
  if(read_bytes < 16){
    i = read__bytes;
    read_bytes += 1;
    for(i, i<16, i++) plain_text[read_bytes] = 0;
  }
  encrypt-this-part-of-file
  fwrite(encBuffer, 1, 16, fpout);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code with spaces.

Comment: @UjjwalSingh, better? :)

Comment: As far as being corret goes: does the application that is decrypting the file knows to drop the trailing zeroes?

Comment: Shouldn't `plain_text[read_bytes] = 0;` be `plain_text[i] = 0;`?

Comment: Are you sure that `for(i, i<16, i++)` actually compiles? I suggest you copy and paste the code exactly as you wrote it, otherwise there may be some typo somewhere that you're not copying correctly.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes i haven't thought about this :-( what can i do instead of this ugly code??

Comment: @OmriBarel i haven't tried, i wrote the code directly when i was writing the question! it is a PoC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, this would be correct...

```
if(read_bytes < 16)
{
    for(i = read_bytes; i<16; i++)
    {
        plain_text[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

...if you'd actually needed it.

But you don't need to zero the remaining part of the array as you have already cleared it with...

```
memset(plain_text, 0, sizeof(plain_text));
```

...that you're calling before each invokation of fread.

Comment: you're right! :D but there will be a problem when i'm going to decrypt the file because my last array could have some zeroes and i have to tell to the decrypt function how many zeroes there are right?

Comment: Ok, so don't worry about zeroing the remaining part of the array (the one that was not read from the file) and let the decrypt function get from read_bytes the length of the array (16 or less) and act properly. I can't help more since nothing is known about that function!